# Expert system returns this "catch/1" error

Tags: prolog, expert-system

Below in code, the representation of a expert system to give response to a pattern of problems in a device (in this case, a mobile one), with the result being the probable cause of the issues, but as you may have seen in the title, this throw a especific error:

```
go :- catch(Problem),
print("Your problem is probably a"),
print(Problem),
print("Issue"),
nl.

input(Question) :-
write('You have problems such as the follwing:'),
write(Question),
write('?'),
read(output),
nl,
(( output == yes; output == y)
->
assert(yes(Question));
assert(no(Question)), fail).

:- dynamic yes/3, no/1.
verify(Problem):-
(yes(Problem)
-> true;
(no(Problem)
->
fail;
input(Problem))).
undo :-  retract(yes(_)),fail.
undo :-  retract(no(_)),fail.
undo.

grasp(low_battery) :- low_battery,!.
grasp(software_problem) :- software_problem,!.
grasp(hardware_problem) :- low_battery,!.
%grasp(virus_or_memory_issue) :- virus_or_memory_issue,!.

low_battery :-
verify(phone_not_recharged),
verify(charger_not_working).

software_problem :-
verify(device_turns_on_but_crashes),
verify(some_program_dont_work),
verify(more_than_one_program_crashes_after_awhile),
verify(some_programs_are_not_updated_or_deprecated).

%hardware_problem :-
%verify(device_dont_turn_on),
%verify(device_warmth_frequently),
%verify(screen_exhibits_atipical_visual_patters),
%verify(problems_began_or_intensified_after_fall_or_any_damage).
```

As a result, the given console is as follows:

```
ERROR: Unknown procedure: catch/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         catch/3
ERROR: 
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] catch(_4812)
ERROR:   [10] go at c:/users/victo/onedrive/documentos/prolog/sistema_especialista.pl:1
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user:go) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1158
   Exception: (11) [user] catch(_4356) ?
```

Searching for material I've found very little on such matter, and other algoritms I've found were quite not like this one. Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: It's `catch/1` not `catcher/3` nor `catch/3`. You need to define `catch/1` first, most probably by prompting the user and then diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I don't think I get what you mean, how do I define a catch/1 and what prompts a user in this context?  (new on prolog, so I might be missing things)